# What term means someone with no tact?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term to describe someone with no tact, someone who frequently says things that offend others? Malicious intent it not necessary, but a lack of awareness.

Sample sentence: Sally is a ___ and is always saying things that offends her coworkers.

Answer (score 3):

Someone who lacks tact is [tactless](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/tactless).

Looing at the synonyms of tactless, we have [boorish](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/boorish)

> Rough and bad-mannered; coarse.

Someone who is boorish is a [boor](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/boor)

> A rough and bad-mannered person.

Which can be put in the sample sentence as

> Sally is a boor and is always saying things that offends her coworkers

Comment: I wouldn't say that  _boorish_ was an exact synonym of _tactless_; it implies crude behaviour rather than just insensitive words. I can't think of a noun for a tactless person. You would just have to say something like "Sally is often tactless".

Comment: One of the points of demanding a sample sentence is that the selected word has to fit that sentence. This sentence requires a noun so that's what I supplied. Had there been a more direct noun meaning tactless I'd have used that.

Answer (score 1):

To look for an actual *noun* is difficult. But when somebody lacks tact, they often say or do things that are impolite or unconsidered and that make other people uncomfortable. It's how such a person makes other people feel that I think is key.

As such, I think a close noun would be [**embarrassment**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embarrassment):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : something that embarrasses
>   // the scandal was a major *embarrassment*

So:

> Sally is an *embarrassment* and is always saying things that offend her coworkers.

It's often applied more to things than to people, but I have heard it applied to people too. If applying it to a person, I think it comes quite close to the noun version of *tactless*.

---

Having said that, I think using the adjective *tactless* would still be a better general choice when it comes to describing such a person—mainly because there is no noun that carries exactly the same meaning.